# Как обрабатывать и отсылать данные в android, на сервер для формирования https соединения?

Tags: android, android-sdk, http, безопасность, криптография

Как организовать https соед в android? Для начала пройдусь по схеме, чтобы было понятнее, что я именно хочу:

- Клиент запрашивает у сервера безопасное соединение и отсылает данные о используемом алгоритме шифрования и т.д
  Сервер высылает сертификат с ключём
- Клиент проверяет сертификат на достоверность
- Если все норм, то отсылаю на серв сгенерированный ключ для симметричного шифрования, который я зашифровал открытым ключём сервера
- Сервер, приняв это, подтверждает, что соединение установлено
- Следом я шлю все сообщения, зашифровав их перед этим своим ключём, сервер расшифровывает их им же

Так вот для начала спрошу, правильная ли схема (если не то - подскажите где и что не так)? Если да, то как мне сделать всю эту клиентскую логику, а именно: Как обрабатывать сертификат, генерировать ключ, добавлять MAC к запросу и прочее. С помощь каких библиотек это делать?

**P.s** понимаю что вопрос очень общий, так что можно просто описать общие инструменты и краткие пояснения-рекомендации к ним, но если решитесь написать развернутый ответ - буду очень благодарен.

**P.p.s** все что прочитал в интернете, не внесло никакой ясности о том, как организовывать соединение от а до я.

Comment: Непонятно, в чем именно вопрос? То, что вы описали, очень похоже на работу SSL. Когда вы указываете в качестве протокола HTTPS, все это происходит автоматически. Если у вас нет каких-то дополнительных требований, например, к протоколам или дополнительной проверке сертификата, ничего делать не надо.

Comment: Начните отсюда: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html

Comment: Ну да я по сути описал протокол ssl и мне непонятно как его реализовать на android, а эту статься я читал и я сности она не внесла

Comment: SSL вам дали из коробки, и он включится по умолчанию, если URL начинается с `https://`. Ничего специально делать не надо. Если того, что "из коробки" мало, то дополните вопрос деталями.

Comment: Т.е из коробки делается автоматически вся та схема что я описал выше?Или я что-то не так понимаю?

Comment: Если да то как retrofit узнает например о используемом методе хэширования запроса и других деталях. Я к чему все это спрашиваю,просто я запрос с retrofito-м уже составлял и указывая адрес https в урле у меня запрос тупо не проходил

Comment: Вообще используемый метод хэширования согласовывается на этапе работы протокола TLS Handshake. Никогда не пользовался Retrofit, но предполагаю, что дело не в этом.